How to install CIFS on RedHat UBI9-minimal?
Trying to mount a Windows share from a UBI9-minimal container.  I've discovered that cifs is not contained in the image.  Trying to install 'cifs-utils' via microdnf seems to indicate it does not exist.  Doing a microdnf repoquery cifs (or *cifs*) yields no results.
How to install cifs-utils on UBI9-minimal to mount a Windows share?
